# Twitter Tabs with vertical text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I use `twitter-bootstrap` for create an interface. 
But I do not know how create `tab-widget` with vertical text.
For text transform i use:

```
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg); 
-moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform-origin:  bottom left;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a less script that will generate that css or ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add custom class.

HTML:

```
<div class="letterP3">Hello</div>
```

CSS:

```
.letterP3 {    
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); 
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); 
       -o-transform: rotate(90deg); 
          transform: rotate(90deg);
            color: #000;
            font-size: 22px;                
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            float: left;        
            vertical-align:top;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/8Rc27/

And CSS3 tool:

http://www.css3maker.com/text-rotation.html

Answer (score 0):

@lito - I have implemented left/right vertical bootstrap tabs [here](http://cdpn.io/itrqp) - with the text rotation you described. Hope this helps.